# Alternative for PDO in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pdo

Working on a new project in CakePHP, completed the basic requirements client requested and works fine in my local system. But when i uploaded it to server i encountered

Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php on line 210

So on referring some links i knew that its about enabling the PDO in server. So i sent some link regarding enabling of PDO in server to client(server is managed by him). So he replied as

This is not supported in the current hosting, What is the alternate option?

So is there any alternative to PDO in cakephp to make database connection?

Comment: I suggest you to fix the problem that is with your PDO connection.

Comment: @Sourabh well i cant enable it cuz i already mentioned it was maintained by my client. i sent links on how to enabled PDO to my client but he responded as hosting doesnt support it.. Thats why i was looking for an alternative

Comment: Ok, you can use the mysqli_* functions then, or either see if that hosting has settings to enable PDO

Comment: CakePHP 2.x and above requires PDO. There is no alternative (unless you want to write a driver yourself which uses msql_* functions instead of PDO). It must be an extremely shitty webhost which doesn't provide PDO.

Comment: yes ADmad is right because even free hosting services provide PDO support

Comment: @ADmad yes you were. thats what am basically wondering, Even free servers provides support. Seems like i had to contact him again. Just to make sure again that error is encountered when PDO is missing in Apache right?

Comment: No, it's missing in PHP. You need to get pdo and pdo_mysql extensions installed and enabled in PHP.

Comment: ah yes PHP sorry for mentioning Apache.. in php.ini